# HP SUM for mezzanine cards

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I'm using SUM 5.3.5, and in the HTML report I see Mezz#1, Mezz#2, Mezz#3 in the header. Further down in the "BLADE SERVERS (Quick Glance)" section I see values for the type of mezzanine card, when installed. Where is it hiding the firmware VERSION of the mezzanine card?

Thanks